# How to show that direct product of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times...$ is not projective as a $\mathbb Z$ module?

Tags: modules, projective-module

How to show that  direct product of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times...$ is not projective as a $\mathbb Z$ module?

I know that $\mathbb Z$ is a free $\mathbb Z$ module since it has $\{1\}$ as a basis.

An $R-$  module $P$ is said to  projective if $P$ is a direct summand of  a free $R-$  module .Also an $R-$  module is free if it is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of the underlying ring.

However I cant use these facts to arrive at my proof.How to do it?

Comment: The only proof I know is by showing that $\hom(\prod\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z)=\bigoplus\Bbb Z$, but for a free abelian group, the $\hom$ with $\Bbb Z$ must be much larger.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module) as well as [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500607/a-direct-product-of-projective-modules-which-is-not-projective).

Comment: Using the definition, the identity map of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ doesn't lift to a map $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ under the quotient map of the latter to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ itself. This can be generalized to any torsion abelian group.