# Is there an alternative proof for that $\prod_{\mathbb N}\mathbb Z$ is not a free $\mathbb Z$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module, free-modules

> **Question.** Prove that $\prod\limits_{\mathbb N}\mathbb Z$ is not a free $\mathbb Z$-module.

I have searched over MSE and found answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1336428/381305). The question I want to ask is, whether there is an alternative proof for this fact, as the solution provided in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module) used the fact that free $\mathbb Z$-module has no non-trivial divisible submodule to force a contradiction in cardinality. In particular, in both questions above it is mentioned that counting the cardinality of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\prod\limits_{\mathbb N}\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z)$ can also lead to a contradiction if $\prod\limits_{\mathbb N}\mathbb Z$ is free, so I also would like to ask how to prove the **Question** in this way. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Doesn't the accepted answer already mention a theorem of Specker?

Comment: I think Specker's original proof (published in 1950 in Portugaliae Math., vol. 9, pp. 131-140) is different from the proofs on MSE.

Comment: Here is the exercise in Dummit&Foote that walks through the proof (I find it very easy to understand): https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL5Si.png  This is from pg. 358 in the 3rd edition.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, but only knowing "a theorem of Specker" I cannot find the exact source of it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you! I will check this source..

Comment: @SteveD Thank you! It is indeed easy to understand, yet is also rather alike one of the answers mentioned above...